# How to error handle when lambda time out from Frontend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

Frontend(Angular) is using lambdas via APIGateway. A few api calls get timeout after 29sec while lambda keeps running another 1m 30s and time out also. Gateway timeout happens without getting any response from lambda.

### I see 504 return code only when API-Gateway times out. That's all it gets.

Knowing all these limitations I can't change, my question is what Frontend can do when this api-gateway timeout happens? There is no response body coming back rather than header. The only thing is the response header with 504 status code.  Can it detect and display an error message like " Timeout occurred " or something?

Comment: Did you try increasing the Lambda Timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hard limit of 30 seconds that you can't change. You AWS Lambda can run longer, hard limit is 15 minutes, but API Gateway breaks at 30 seconds.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: updated my question. i want to know how to handle that situation.